# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror, rails-flash

Here is my SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
        sign_in user
        redirect_to user
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
        render 'new'
    end
end


def destroy
end
```

end

Here is the routes.rb

```
resources :sessions, only: [:new,:create,:destroy]
```

also the respective routes for new and destroy views.

Here is the new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title , "Sign in")%>
<div id="signin_page" class="hero-unit container-fluid">
<h1>Sign In</h1>
<div class="row span6">
<%= simple_form_for :sessions, url: '/sessions', html: {:class=> 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
<%= f.input :email, label: "Email", placeholder: "Enter email",required: true%>
<%= f.input :password, label: "Password", placeholder: "Enter Password", required: true%>
<p id="signin_button"><%= f.button :submit, "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary span2" %> 
    New user? <%=link_to "Sign up now!", '/signup'%></p>

<% end %>
</div>
```

The error is like.
[image]

what I'm trying to implement is that, **the sign in success/failure shouldrender the respective views with the flash messages.**
Where am I going wrong.
I'm newbie to ROR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `sessions` instead of `session` i.e. Use

```
params[:sessions][:email]
```

instead of

```
params[:session][:email]
```

As your form says `sessions` i.e. `simple_form_for :sessions`.

But in controller you are accessing `params[:sessions]` which is `nil` and then calling `[:email]` on it hence it is giving error

```
undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
```

hence change

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
```

To

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:sessions][:email].downcase)
if user && user.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password])
```

and then it should work

Comment: That was a silly mistake on my side. Thanks for the quick reply. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because `params[:session][:email]` value is nil.

based on your printscreen it should be `params[:sessions][:email]`

Answer (score 0):

I think a better alternative to

```
user = User.find_by(email: params[:sessions][:email].downcase)
```

could be:

```
user = User.find_by(email: params[:sessions][:email].downcase) if params[:sessions].try(:[],:email)
```

This means that user would be nil if either params[:sessions] or params[:sessions][:email] is nil. I.e. without raising NoMethodError even if params is empty.